# Make WolframAlpha iframe redirect to website

Tags: html, wolframalpha

So I added WolframAlpha as a frame into a webpage (deleted the rest for the time being) and was wondering if there was a way to have search results open on the actual WA website.

ex. If I type 1+1 it will open me https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2B1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%;">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                overflow:hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="height: 100%;margin:0;padding:0">
        <iframe src="https://www.wolframalpha.com/" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width: 50%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Currently it just opens the search result on the page

Answer (score 0):

No.

Only Wolfram Alpha can control the target of their links and forms.